# Prevent another application from losing focus in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, controls, topmost

I'm creating some software to keep my students on task.  I've set it up so that I can control certain aspects of their computer from my computer.  Problem is, I'm not sure how to control other applications from my application.  I mostly just want to prevent it from being minimized.  Some students like to switch screens quickly when I walk by.  I would just like to make sure that it is always on top until I specify otherwise.

Thanks for any help.  I'm using VB.net, I'm using the 3.5 .net framework for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main form, set the following two flags:

1) `MinimizeBox` property to False. This will prevent them from minimizing your app.

2) `TopMost` property to True. This will keep, for the most part, other windows from displaying over the top of yours.

There may be some situations in which TopMost doesn't work exactly as you want (for example, if another app that also specified TopMost was started before yours), but most standard applications don't set this flag.

Comment: No, I want to prevent OTHER windows from being minimized.  For instance, Internet Explorer or Microsoft Word.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now. Updated answer with another flag to set. To clarify, you can't really affect the other applications in the system, you can only really modify yours to approximate the desired outcome.